# Regular Expression Troubles with resource keys

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have internal function calls that evaluate resource keys. I am interested in parsing them as text files.

My patterns are `Translate.Key(StuffToGrab)`, `translatekey(StuffToGrab)`, `caption=StuffToGrab`, `header=StuffToGrab` and the most tricky one, `<%$ Resources:Resource, StuffToGrab %>`

There are the regular expressions I have came up with for them:

```
Translate.Key(\S+)
TranslateKey(\S+)
caption="".+?""
headerName="".+?""
<%\$\s*Resources:.+?%>
```

However, they don't return 'StuffToGrab' and return other information that I have to then remove, slowing down my process.

Comment: Are you applying the regex all at the same time or? (I'm not familiar with vb, but that made me curious...)

Comment: Yeah, with a | to say or.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is "StuffToGrab", then what you really want to do is match text that is preceeded by certain characters (rather than actually matching those character). You can do this in .NET by using zero-width assertions, specifically [lookbehind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookbehind_assertion): `(?<=precedingchars)`

Parentheses are special characters, but `\S` just happens to match them. Even so, you may want to specify them explicitly.

Example:

```
(?<=Translate.Key\()[^)]+
(?<=TranslateKey\()[^)]+
(?<=caption=")[^"]+
(?<=headerName=")[^"]+
(?<=<%\$\s*Resources:\s*).*?(?=\s*%>)
```

See the working example here: http://fiddle.re/fph0a

Comment: Suggested edit: `(?=precedingchars)` to become `(?<=precedingchars)` :)

Comment: Can you explain to me the patterns? I have never seen square brackets, and the last pattern doesn't work properly.

Comment: @user2417731 - Character classes, and other constructs, have already been explained thoroughly on the MSDN website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx